# angular 2 passing params in route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, routerlink

I have a component from where i need to pass data to another component on click of button so I have used `[routerLink]` property in anchor like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/employeedetail' , name, address, 
detail3 , detail4, detail5, detail6 , detail7, detail8 , 
detail9, detail10></a>
```

defined corresponding route in app.route.ts

```
    {
    path: 'employeedetail/:name/:address/:detail3 /:detail4
    /:detail5 /:detail6/:detail7 /:detail8 /:detail9 /:detail10 ',
    component : employeedetailComponent
    }
```

In perfect world it should work but it does not as it given an error saying

> zone.js:355Unhandled Promise rejection: Unsupported number of argument
>   for pure functions: 11 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   Error: Unsupported number of argument for pure functions: 11(…) Error:
>   Unsupported number of argument for pure functions: 11

I researched about this and found that angular2 router fails when there are 10 elements in inline template ,I tried out by removing last param in URL (detail10) and no error .

**Question is how to pass these large number of params in url using [routerlink] or should I be using different approach for passing data from one component to another component ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use queryParams to pass params in the url.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/employeedetail' , name, address]" [queryParams]="{detail3: detail3, detail4: detail4}">Somewhere</a>
```

Using query params are better for optional params, it makes your url more readable.

Comment: my requirement is not for optional params, it kind of required params in order for other page to function properly

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to the component that prepares the route and pass the result instead of building it in the template

```
  class MyComponent {
    get employeeDetailLink() {
      return ['/employeedetail' , name, address, 
detail3 , detail4, detail5, detail6 , detail7, detail8 , 
detail9, detail10];
    }
  }
```

and use it like

```
<a [routerLink]="employeeDetailLink"
```

This limitation was removed recently (don't know if it's already released) https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12710

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12233

Comment: how do i retrieve params back on other page , I am not sure if I can use `this.router.snapshot.params["param1"];` to get passed param values